# Trying to do some trick by adding registry value thru vb6 but using shell command. Succeed, but it didn't show on registry

Tags: vba, shell, vb6

I am trying to creating registry with shell reg add like this below:

```
Shell ("cmd /k cd %userprofile% && reg add ""HKLM\Software\myprogram"" /v ""status"" /t REG_DWORD /d ""1"" /f"), vbHide
```

For some reason, myprogram didn't show on the registry key. Am I missing something?

Comment: When I do vbnormalfocus, it opened CMD and it said "the operations completed successfully", but it won't shows up on regedit. Did the same code with cmd, it exist just fine (with "" changed to " ofc).

Comment: It will have been redirected. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/registry-redirector